# Total Size of Hard Disk using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to find the total size of Inbuilt hard disk.
This code gives me just the size of C: drive.

```
long diskSize= new File("/").getTotalSpace();
```

I use this code but it also adding the size of drive on Network.

```
        long diskSize= 0;
        File[] drives = File.listRoots();
        if (drives != null && drives.length > 0) {
        for (File aDrive : drives) {
        diskSize=diskSize+(aDrive.getTotalSpace()/1000000000); //(1000000000)Converting to GB
        }
        }
```

Comment: as `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace()` you may want to divide by a `float` in order to not have `integer` division

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can Use below code to get the total space of all directories

```
       package haneef.code.check;

       import java.io.File;

       import java.util.ArrayList;

       import java.util.List;

       public class DirSpace

       {

            static Double val=1000000000.00;

            public static void main(String[] args) 

            {
                 File file=new File("\\");
                 List<Double> values=new ArrayList<Double>();
                 File[] list=file.listRoots();
                 for(File driver:list)
                 {
                      Double driveGB=driver.getTotalSpace()/val;
                      System.out.println("Driver "+driver+" Space - "+driveGB);
                      values.add(driveGB);
                      Double cDrive=values.get(0);
                      for(int i=1;i<values.size();i++)
                      {
                            Double totalSpace=cDrive+values.get(i);
                            System.out.println("Final --- Total space is "+totalSpace);
                      }
                 }

             }

        }
```

Console output -

Driver C:\ Space - 107.583893504

Driver D:\ Space - 212.381724672

Final --- Total space is 319.965618176